# My message box goes through when I do not want it to

Tags: c#

So Everything here seems correct I was wondering why the 'else' goes through. When I put in the correct username and password the tells me "You are now logged in!" but then it tells me "You have entered an incorrect username or password!"  (I am using C#) (New Programmer Alert!)

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (username_txtb.Text == username && password_txtb.Text == password)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in!");
        }
        else
        {
        }
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect username or password!");
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Ah, sorry. New to the forums too. Please excuse me. I thought like all others you would need to ask a new question. My apologies.

Comment: @user3002617 In general yes, for a different query you should ask a new question. But in this case, you seemed to just rush to your code after reading half of the solution, without attempting to understand the posts, and right away you've posted another question. You wouldn't have to, if you'd just read the answers more carefully :) Also - please accept the answers you found most helpful. And welcome to SO! ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a lexical error that the debugger will find.

Answer (score 3):

```
        else
        {//remove
        }//this part
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect username or password!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra set of curly braces, so the code to show your second message box is always executed:

Try this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (username_txtb.Text == username && password_txtb.Text == password)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect username or password!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `else` branch is empty due to braces. It should be removed.

Change following

```
else
        {
        }
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect username or password!");
        }
```

to

```
 else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect username or password!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have placed to many brackets, you open the else and close it immediately. rewrite your code like this

```
   if (username_txtb.Text == username && password_txtb.Text == password)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are now logged in!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered an incorrect username or password!");
    }
```